# MongoDB Direct Query with PowerBI

Tags: mongodb, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Has anyone had success building a custom connector to enable DirectQuery when connecting to MongoDB? I have come across this solution that seems to be close to what I am trying to figure out:
[DirectQuery With Postgres from PowerBI Desktop](https://medium.com/just-readr-the-instructions/directquery-with-postgres-from-powerbi-desktop-f3d8c4dc5e15)

Being that the MongoDB connector "broadcasts" the database as a MySql db, any MySql connector should work just fine.

Following those steps in the guide I am able to connect to my MongoDB and see the data source tables:
[image: table] However, I am unable to create visuals with them.. I get the following error:

[image: Error]

Does anyone have any hints on what might be causing the error with this visualization?

It is not a possibility for me to just pay for a custom connector from Cdata, progress, etc. so I am going down the path of either building my own or finding a solution that is already out there.

Edit:

PowerQuery Code (M) from Advanced Editor Window:

```
let

    Source = ODBCMySQLDirect.Database("MongoUnicode"),
    Test_Database = Source{[Name="Test",Kind="Database"]}[Data],
    zips_Table = Test_Database{[Name="zips",Kind="Table"]}[Data]

in

    zips_Table
```

Edit:

One interesting thing I found is that if I use data that is summed it will be displayed on the visual. Any other data breaks it.

[image: summarized]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you found the MySQL branch of my custom connector. Unfortunately, I have no means of proceeding forward on that connector until [my issue](https://github.com/microsoft/DataConnectors/issues/209) on Microsoft/DataConnectors repo gets some kind of answer.

The common problems listed here in the microsoft docs are *exactly* the issues that I was running into with this connector:

- queries with filters
- correctly matching database data types to powerbi data types
- SEARCHABLE ODBC attribute
- timestamp precision

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/DataConnectors/blob/master/docs/odbc.md#common-problems